# Can't create access token for my dropbox api. Error: You must be a team administrator to perform this operation

Tags: python, dropbox-api, administrator

So I am trying to make a project where I can upload files to dropbox, but for some reason it won't let me generate an access token? When I ran my script it told me I needed to allow it to use the permission 'files.content.write'. So I enabled the permission. Now, whenever I try to generate the access token it says:

```
You must be a team administrator to perform this operation
```

which seems completely strange because I am the only one using this - it's my account and there is no team?

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you've also enabled some "team scopes" on your app. Team scopes can only be used by Business teams, and can only be authorized by team admins.

If you're not on a team and don't need any team-specific functionality, you should disable the team scopes on your app and try again. (For reference, 'files.content.write' is a user scope, not a team scope.)

Comment: Working now - but it comed up with the error:
UploadWriteFailed(reason=WriteError('malformed_path', None)

Comment: @MiniMinnow That would indicate an issue with the `path` value you're supplying. If you're still having trouble with that, open a new post with the details of the issue, e.g., a sample `path` value.